# bicep Expected a value of type 'Object', but received a value of type 'Array'

Tags: azure-bicep

I am trying to create a parameter file in json where I declare all sorts of objects in it, I need to create multiple managed identities however I dont want to repeat the code, my aim is to declare an array of managed identity names, and loop through them to create a managed identity.

my parameter file

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {  

        "managedIdentities": {
            "value": {
                "location": "westeurope",
                "mi_names": [
                    "mi-app1",
                    "mi-app2",
                    "mi-app3",
                    "mi-app4"
                ]

            }
        }        

    }
}
```

Module file

param managed_identitites array
param managed_identity_properties object

```
resource create_managed_identity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31'= [for name in my_mi: {
    name: name
    location: 'Westeurope'
  }
]
```

Main file.

```
module CreateManagedIdentity './modules/create_identity.bicep' = {
  name:'CreateManagedIdentity'
  params: {
    managed_identitites: managedIdentities.mi_names
   }
}
```

Its complaining of the data type, if i pass an object, it complains that it wants an array, if i pass an array it complains that it wants an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create_identity.bicep`

```
param managedIdentities array
param location string

resource create_managed_identity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31' = [ for name in managedIdentities: {
  name: name
  location: location
} ]
```

`main.bicep`

```
param managedIdentities object

module CreateManagedIdentity './modules/create_identity.bicep' = {
  name:'CreateManagedIdentity'
  params: {
    managedIdentities: managedIdentities.mi_names
    location: managedIdentities.location
   }
}
```

`parameters.json`

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {  
        "managedIdentities": {
            "value": {
                "location": "westeurope",
                "mi_names": [
                    "mi-app1",
                    "mi-app2",
                    "mi-app3",
                    "mi-app4"
                ]

            },
            "type": "object"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]